# Is there an algorithm to design 3 and n dimensional honeycombs or tessellations?

Tags: algorithms, dimension-theory-analysis, tessellations

I have looked into creating multiple dimensional honeycombs, and I can't find an algorithm or methodology for 3 or more dimensions. Is there a general algorithm or heuristic that can be used?

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer.

For three dimensions   if you want all cells to be identical see here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Space-FillingPolyhedron.html

Without that restriction you can build the [tetrahedral - octahedral truss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedral-octahedral_honeycomb), and perhaps others.

In higher dimensions you can make a prism of any space filler in a lower dimension.

I am sure the problem has been studied in general in higher dimensions. I doubt there's an algorithm.